# How to interact with ngx-monaco-editor

Tags: browser-automation, protractor, angular

I have a web page that has the ngx-monaco-editor implemented in angular. But i am not able send any data to the editor using sendKeys() . I tried replacing textContent of the div element but it just displays the text in the editor  but the other components does not detect that the text was entered.

Is there a way to properly send input to the ngx-monaco-editor using selenium protractor?

An example website would be :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-monaco-editor-example

I am not able to send values to the editor

**Code i tried:**

```
await browser.get('https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-monaco-editor-example')   

await browser.sleep(10000)

await element(by.xpath('(//*[@class="view-line"])[1]')).sendKeys('some test')
```

**Error i get:**

```
Element <div class="view-line"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not sure about the locator then you can **use the action class sendKeys** method to interact with the field.

Here, it interacts with the active (currently focused ) element.

So the first step is to **bring the element to focus,** this can be done by just clicking it:

```
await browser.get('https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-monaco-editor-example')      
await browser.sleep(10000)
await  $('[class="view-line"]').click()
await browser.sleep(4000)
```

Now **you can see the cursor is at the below place:**

[image]

Now **you can interact with the element using browser.actions():**

```
await browser.actions().sendKeys('This is test').perform();
```

this will **send input to the currently active element:**

[image]

**Now let us look deeper to find out the locator:**

We now know that the sendKey using action works, so we can find the locator from the active element:

The outerHTML of the active element gives the locator:

```
await  $('[class="view-line"]').click()
let test = await browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement()
console.log("outer");
console.log(await test.getAttribute('outerHTML'))
//await test.sendKeys("a=1;c=a+10;") if you try this you can see even this sends data
```

**Output:**

```
<textarea data-mprt="6" class="inputarea" wrap="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" aria-label="Editor content;Press Alt+F1 for Accessibility Options." role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" aria-haspopup="false" aria-autocomplete="both" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 18px; top: 0px; left: 562px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"></textarea>
```

So the input element is the text area, and you can send data to this element. Try

```
$('textarea[class="inputarea"]').sendKeys('something');
```

**Note:** you can use this approach of getting outer HTML of the active element in cases where you are not sure about the element but browser actions work.

**Summary:**

**So you can use two approaches:**

**1:**

```
await elem.click()
await browser.actions().sendKeys('This is test').perform();
```

**2:**

```
await elem.click()
let field= await browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement()
await field.sendKeys("HI");
```

**you can find the locator or element as:**

```
await field.getAttribute('outerHTML');
```

Comment: That worked out  perfectly,Thank you